# Need responsive iframe layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want design a page with 4 `iframes` in it and responsive layout for it. Below is the code which works on desktop but on ipad this is not working properly.
And I want responsive layout for it.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nilam/63meQ/)

Comment: Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/nilam/63meQ/

Comment: I need to include title for each iframe. Can I do this without relative positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Responsive layout use CSS Media Queries**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YR4ne/4/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="h_iframe">
        <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9KunP3sZyI0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="h_iframe">
        <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9KunP3sZyI0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="h_iframe">
        <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9KunP3sZyI0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="h_iframe">
        <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9KunP3sZyI0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
.wrapper {
    padding: 0 1%;
    width:98%;
}
.h_iframe {
    float:left;
    margin:1% 2%;
    width:46%;
}
iframe {
    width:100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .wrapper {
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:0;
        width:95%;
    }
    .h_iframe {
        margin:0;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems fine solution but when we will edit height in % iframe height doesn't change. Only if we will give height in px it will change.

Comment: And don't want height in pixels

Comment: In responsive layout height is not required to add, I remove height from my code and update the code. please check.

Comment: I need to include title for each iframe. Can I do this without relative positioning.

Comment: I have charts in iframes but those are getting cropped. Can I have better solution on this

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/7WRHM/1564/)**</kbd>

Here is complete responsive 4 iframe on page.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="h_iframe1">
        <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9KunP3sZyI0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="h_iframe2">
        <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9KunP3sZyI0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="h_iframe3">
        <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9KunP3sZyI0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="h_iframe4">
        <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9KunP3sZyI0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
.h_iframe1 iframe {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
}
.h_iframe2 iframe {
    position:absolute;
    top: 25%;
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
}
.h_iframe3 iframe {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:25%;
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
}
.h_iframe4 iframe {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Explained solution based on Youtube iframe http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: I need to include title for each iframe. Can I do this without relative positioning.